conditionally copy XML elements using XSLT with extra namespace?
I have an XML beginning with these lines
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TRANSFER xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.interlis.ch/INTERLIS2.3" xmlns="http://www.interlis.ch/INTERLIS2.3">
  <HEADERSECTION VERSION="2.3" SENDER="ACME">
    <MODELS>
      <MODEL NAME="DSS_2015_LV95" VERSION="13.11.2018" URI="http://www.vsa.ch/models" />
    </MODELS>
  </HEADERSECTION>
  <DATASECTION>
    <DSS_2015_LV95.Siedlungsentwaesserung BID="999">
      <DSS_2015_LV95.Siedlungsentwaesserung.Abwasserbauwerk_Text_123>
        <TextPos>
          <COORD>
      .....
      <DSS_2015_LV95.Siedlungsentwaesserung.Abwasserbauwerk_Text_123>
        <TextPos>
          <COORD>
      .....
      <DSS_2015_LV95.Siedlungsentwaesserung.Abwasserbauwerk_Text_456>
        <Value>
          <Price>
      .....
      <DSS_2015_LV95.Siedlungsentwaesserung.Abwasserbauwerk_Text_789>
        <Text>
          <Cost>
      .....

I found a lot of examples (and also one which helped me with my special namespace..) to "copy everything but ....123":

make a template which copies everything
add a second template which ignores "...123"

But now I have the opposite task to "copy only ...123" incl. header and consider the namespace. The way described above - "copy everything but 456 and 789" - can not be used, because I don't know what to be ignored.
I don't show the codes I tried (based on xsl:copy ..) because it is a confusing collection of trash, but I messed something up match and select..
I hope my description is understandable - sorry for my unprofessional knowledge, and many thanks in advance.

So basically you want someone to write your code for you? And do it without having a complete XML input example, and without seeing the expected result? Seriously?

It would help if you showed the output you want to achieve. Also, don't be afraid to show your attempt, even if it is a "confusing collection of trash". Looking at your failed attempt helps us understand what concept it is that you have failed to grasp, which enables us to give a much more constructive response.

While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.
All within the question as text, no images.

Is the name of the HEADERSECTION known when writing the XSLT? Or how is the code supposed to decide to copy only ...123 incl. header? Is that because these elements are preceding the ...123? Anyway, consider to spell out a well-formed sample input document and the corresponding result you want to create.

I want to create a new xml containing everything, but from  only the complete children elements <DSS_2015_LV95.Siedlungsentwaesserung.Abwasserbauwerk_Text_123>.
I don't know what else will be in , so I can not define what "not to copy".
But I see - without clear snippets it's not easy. I will add them soon. Thanks for your comments in the meantime.

Based on your latest comment you might want something like
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:il="http://www.interlis.ch/INTERLIS2.3">
  
  <xsl:template match="il:DATASECTION//node()[not(descendant-or-self::il:DSS_2015_LV95.Siedlungsentwaesserung.Abwasserbauwerk_Text_123|ancestor::il:DSS_2015_LV95.Siedlungsentwaesserung.Abwasserbauwerk_Text_123)]"/> 

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

What is not specified is whether you want an empty DATASECTION to be copied to the output if there are no DSS_2015_LV95.Siedlungsentwaesserung.Abwasserbauwerk_Text_123 at all or whether in that case the DATASECTION element should not appear in the output. The code as posted would create an empty DATASECTION if there are no DSS_2015_LV95.Siedlungsentwaesserung.Abwasserbauwerk_Text_123 children or descendants.

works as expected. Thanks a lot!
